# Fetching Data from Dynamic Form having multiple dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void createnewTable(int ts,int sid)
{
    SubjectClass s1 = new SubjectClass();
    List<string> sub = new List<string>();
    sub = s1.returnSubjectList(sid);

    Table timetable = new Table();
    int height = 20;
    Panel1.Attributes.Add("style", "height:" + height.ToString() + "px;");
    for (int i = 1; i <= ts; i++)
    {
        height = height + 20;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Lecture" + (i).ToString();
        td1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        tr.Controls.Add(td1);
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
        {
            TableCell td2 = new TableCell();
            DropDownList drop_sub = new DropDownList();
            drop_sub.ID = "drop" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
            foreach (string s in sub)
            {
                drop_sub.Items.Add(s.ToString());
            }
            drop_sub.Items.Add("No lecture");
            td2.Controls.Add(drop_sub);
            tr.Controls.Add(td2);
            Panel1.Attributes.Add("style", "height:" + height.ToString() + "px;");

        }

        timetable.Controls.Add(tr);

    }
    panel_timetable.Controls.Add(timetable);
}
protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totsub = int.Parse(Session["ts"].ToString());
    Session["ts"] = null;
    List<string> sub = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= totsub; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
        {
            DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();
            drop = (DropDownList)(panel_timetable.FindControl("drop"+i.ToString()+j.ToString()));//here error that Object reference                     //not set to an instance of an object.
            string str = drop.SelectedValue;
            sub.Add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I would like to create a new table which is having multiple DropDownList controls and at the button click of save I would like to save the filled data in the dropdownlist to table.  At the FindControl, it is showing an error that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this error because dynamically created controls get flushed after postback. 
You need to recreate them to make them available, or you can use alternative way.
 For example access the dropdown list from javascript on button click and use it in js. You can store its result in hidden field which will be available in code behind.

Check this link:
http://www.learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx